# My App Crashes after sometime onLocationChanged(),

Tags: android, locationmanager

this is my LocationListener... i want my location listener to get the city only once, and store it into sharedpreference, then after that i want to use that location for other purpose.All works good, but it crashes after sometime.

```
loclistener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                //tvLoc.append("\n" + addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                tvLoc.setText(cityName);
                editor.putString(CITYNAME,cityName);
               // Toast.makeText(Emergencylist.this,"CityName saved :"+cityName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                editor.commit();


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        };
```

Comment: attach the error plz

Comment: Is there any stacktrace? Where exactly is it crashing?

Comment: post your logcat..........

Comment: its android Runtime Exception onLocationChanged(); @oleg Khilidov

Comment: PLEASE SHARE YOUR LOGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is **dangerous**:
If a exception occurs... **addresses** is **NULL**.

```
 List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
```

Solution to avoid unexpected crashes:

```
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses = null;
                    try {
                        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if((addresses && addresses.isEmpty()) || !addresses) { return; }
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    tvLoc.setText(cityName);                                         editor.putString(CITYNAME,cityName);                   
                    editor.commit();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Also if the list is just empty the `addresses.get(0)` will crash.

Comment: what is the Solution please if u could help @Markus

Comment: Thanku @Markus :) , i got my mistake